# How do you change TTY font size before login?

Tags: login, fonts, tty

I am able to change the font in TTY by adding this script to `~/.profile`:

```
if [ "$TERM" == "linux" ]; then 
    setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Uni3-Terminus32x16.psf.gz
fi
```

However this script is executed after login. The login prompt message is still tiny. How do I change the font size before login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am able to change the font in TTY by adding this script to ~/.profile:

There should be no need for that. You do that with ...

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

- 1st window will ask for encoding. Pick UTF-8.
- 2nd window will ask for character set. Pick "latin".
- 3rd window will ask for the font. Pick Terminus.
- 4th window will ask for font size. And here you can choose a size; Terminus has a few more sizes that the other fonts.

Settings apply after you log in again and run

```
setupcon
```

or after a reboot.